# Passing PHP variables to Mandrill email template

Tags: php, variables, mandrill

How can I receive and use a PHP variable in Mandrill email template?

```
$template_content = array(
                          array(
                                'name' => 'link',
                                'content' => $producturl
                                    ),
                            array(
                                'name' => 'facebooklink',
                                'content' =>      'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$producturl)
                                );
```

I am passing a variable like this.
In the template Product link works fine.

How can I give a link to share on Facebook, I tried as follows but it is not working:

```
<a href="mc:edit="facebooklink""><img src="Facebooksharebutton.png" /></a>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use "facekooklink" in your template and "facebooklink" in your code? Also, a more detailed description of "not working" is always welcome here.

Comment: Yes I want Facebook Share button in my template, So that users can share the product directly from their email

Comment: No, I mean you've spelled it wrong in your template. "face**k**ooklink".

Comment: Sorry, It was a spelling mistake, I corrected it there.

Comment: I am not sure how you did product url. But you can look this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998219/mandrill-editable-template-mcedit-link-href. Or you can move mc:edit="facebooklink" to outside href. Then link is html link with image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send message variable like below using mandrillapp API

```
$message = array(
    'merge_vars' => array(array(
        'vars' =>
        array(
            array(
                'name' => 'FACEBOOKLINK',
                'content' => 'http://www.facebook.com')
    ))));
```

And there in template you have to use *|FACEBOOKLINK| * in href attribute of anchor.